# Is there way to block access to settings in android device?

Tags: android, settings

I create an application and i don't want to allow user to show settings.
User can't run settings via launcher now, but user can run settings via information panel.

I`m using following solution, but with this user can choose what want to open. I wi

```
            <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.settings.SETTINGS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Is there any way to block access to settings in android device?

Thanks in advance

Comment: only with your custom version of android.

Comment: you can only make this happen if you build your own ROM